# Private reference in abstract class

Tags: java, reference, abstract-class, decorator, private

I have this piece of code of decorator pattern:

```
public interface AbstractComponent {

    public void operation();
}


public class Component implements AbstractComponent {

    public void operation() {
        // do something
    }
}


public abstract class AbstractDecorator implements AbstractComponent {

    private AbstractComponent component;

    public AbstractDecorator(AbstractComponent ac) {
        component=ac;
    }

    public void operation() {
        component.operation();
    }
}


public class DecoratorA extends AbstractDecorator {

    public DecoratorA (AbstractComponent ac) {
        super(ac);
    }

    public void addedOperation() {
        // adds features to Component
    }

    public void operation() {
        addedOperation();
        super.operation();
    }
}


public class DecoratorB extends AbstractDecorator {

    public DecoratorB (AbstractComponent ac) {
        super(ac);
    }

    public void addedOperation() {
        // adds features to Component
    }

    public void operation() {
        addedOperation();
        super.operation();
    }
}


public class Tester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AbstractComponent c = new Component();
        AbstractComponent d1 = new DecoratorA(c);
        AbstractComponent d2 = new DecoratorB(d1);
        d2.operation();
    }
}
```

When a `DecoratorA` is created, its constructor calls the superclass constructor that assign the reference `c` to `component`. When a `DecoratorB` is created, its constructor calls the same superclass constructor that assign the reference `d1` to `component`.

My question is: shouldn't `DecoratorB` constructor overwrite the past assignment of `c` to `component`? Or is there some kind of copy of the private reference for every decorator I create? I cannot find a solution, since this reference is private and cannot be inherited by subclasses.

Comment: What is `AbstractComponent`? Why are you implementing it?

Comment: `AbstractComponent` is the interface implemented by `Component` and `AbstractDecorator`. I'm implementing it just because of his `operation()` method, that will be defined differently by the classes which implement the interface.

Comment: Then add to your code the definition of that interface and the relevant method it contains, we are not supposed to guess. What is `Component` also?

Comment: Just added `AbstractComponent` and `Component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: shouldn't `DecoratorB` constructor overwrite the past assignment of `c` to `Component`?'

No. Let's look at a slightly simpler case with exactly the same behavior:

```
class Parent {

    int i;
}

class ChildA extends Parent {}
class ChildB extends Parent {}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent p1 = new ChildA();
        Parent p2 = new ChildB();
        p1.i = 3;
        p2.i = 4;
        System.out.println(p1.i); // Output: 3
    }
}
```

As you can see, the second assignment of `Parent`'s `i` does not change the first (regardless of where you set `i` - in the constructor or anywhere else). This is because:

1. `i` is an *instance* variable. Each instance has allocated memory for its own `int i`.
2. When a class is instantiated, all its superclass hierarchy is also instantiated.

That means that the references `p1` and `p2` hold 2 *different* `int i`s - changing one does not change the other.

**However**, if you would declare `static int i`, that would make `i` a *class* variable which is shared across all instances of the class. In this case, the first assignment would be over-written by the second.

If you are interested in the formalities, there is a lot on this in the JLS...

**Edit:** addressing comments

> In my case, when I create a decorator object, its superclass cannot be instantiated, because it's abstract. So I can't understand yet why every decorator has its own component.

And here we are in the JLS technicalities.

You are correct saying that we can't instantiate an `abstract` class with  `new MyAbstClass()`. JLS 8.1.1.1. `abstract` Classes:

> It is a compile-time error if an attempt is made to create an instance of an `abstract` class using a class instance creation expression (§15.9.1).

But:

> A subclass of an `abstract` class that is not itself `abstract` may be instantiated, resulting in the execution of a constructor for the `abstract` class and, therefore, the execution of the field initializers for instance variables of that class.

When you instantiate your `DecoratorA` and `DecoratorB`, the constructor of `AbstractComponent` is called and the instance field `component` is initialized. So in fact, you do have 2 `component` fields.

Comment: I am not convinced yet. In my case, when I create a decorator object, its superclass cannot be instantiated, because it's abstract. So I can't understand yet why every decorator has its own `component`.

Comment: @Foursnakes I updated my answer with more explanations.

Comment: So, every time I create a decorator its superclass is loaded, even if it's abstract, and its instance fields are loaded as well. Am I right?

Comment: @Foursnakes Decorators are irrelevant, it's a question of inheritance. When you instantiate a class, the whole superclass hierarchy is loaded up to `Object`. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005851/does-an-instance-of-superclass-get-created-when-we-instantiate-an-object). What that questions doesn't address is that the class members are independent of each other, which is your main question.

Comment: Perfect, now I got it all. Thank you so much for your patience and support!

Answer (score 0):

They are different objects, so it shouldn't overwritte the component assignment to c at all.

You have:
object b, whose component is d1, and
object d1, whose component is c

Comment: Ok, but the reference is just one, no? How can I have a `component` of object a and a `component` of object b if this reference is not inherited?