# Parent class extended by multiple child classes, are there going to be multiple instances of parent class created for each child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, extends

If a parent class is extend by multiple child classes, and all the child classes are running parallely, are there going to be multiple instances of parent class created for each child class at run time ? Just being curious.

For a clear understanding, lets consider the below code.

**Parent class:**

```
public class Parent {

    public String a = "Parent";

}
```

**Child class 1:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Child1 extends Parent {

    @Test
    public void child1() {

        a = "Child1";
    }
}
```

**Child class 2:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Child2 extends Parent {

    @Test
    public void child1() {

        a = "Child2";
    }
}
```

Here i want to understand if classes Child1 and Child2 are running parallely, will there be two separate instances (memory spaces) created for Parent class respectively for Child1 and Child2 or both will share common instance (memory space) of Parent class ?

Comment: What do you mean by "will there be two separate instances (memory spaces) created for Parent class"? If you create `new Child1()` instance then it is one instance of Child1 class (it can be treated as *representation* of Parent type, but it is still instance of Child1 not Parent). Also what do you mean by "Child1 and Child2 are running parallely"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005900/3959856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> are there going to be multiple instances of parent class created for
>   each child class at run time ?

The short answer is no.

The thing is that Java will create only two instances in this case - both of child classes. Whenever you use `extends` keyword you tell Java to **extend a blueprint of objects, not objects themselves**, which means that the instances are completely independent of each other if to speak about memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks @DayloZatorsky, that is what exactly i wanted to know. :)