# In JavaFX, is an instance of class Pane an individual node?

Tags: java, javafx, nodes

Because typical nodes like Circle or Square are instances of the class Node and Pane is a subclass of Parent which is a subclass of Node, thus, an instance of class Pane used as the root node is technically one individual node. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is an *individual node* ? And what is not an *individual node* ?

Comment: Please clarify the concept of an "_individual node_". I interpret that to mean "_single node_" which necessitates the opposite ("_not an individual node_") to mean "_multiple nodes_". How could a single object instance of `Node` be more than a "_single node_"?

Comment: An individual node in pane/scene is an individual shape like a circle or a line(which are technically objects of the class Node).

Comment: But every `Node` is an "individual node". Can you give an example of what you consider to _not_ be an "individual node"?

Comment: by 'every Node' you mean every 'instance' of Node? I guess I can rephrase my question as "is an instance of class Pane used as the root node an object of class Node?"

Comment: Yes, any instance whose concrete type is a subclass of `Node` _is-a_ `Node`. For instance, if you have `Pane pane = new Pane()` then `pane instanceof Node` will return `true`. This is how inheritance works.

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005851/does-an-instance-of-superclass-get-created-when-we-instantiate-an-object

Answer (score 2):

An object of class [`Pane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) will always be an instance of `Node` because Pane is a subclass of Node

```
Class Pane :
java.lang.Object
  javafx.scene.Node
    javafx.scene.Parent
      javafx.scene.layout.Region
        javafx.scene.layout.Pane
```

---

This means :

- `p instance of Node` will be true, when `p` is a `Pane`
- `Node p = new Pane();` is ok

Comment: I think I understand it clearly. thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NewLearner If the answer satisfies you, you may accept it, if not leave a comment to explain what is missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're getting at I think. You're asking if the Pane's inheritance hierarchy classes are all floating around along with the Pane. The answer is no, they are not and yes, it is a single Node.

When an inheritance hierarchy is instantiated, it is AS IF all the code in each of those parents AND the code from the child, in your case Pane, were all struffed into one class, which you instantiate by calling Pane().

It's one big binary blob with all the members and methods of all its parents.

The Java language API lets you treat it as if it were three different objects in the sense that you can cast it down  the hierarchy and create references to it which are higher up the hierarchy and generally treat it "as if" it was a Node a Container and a Pane at any given time.

But only one instance of a Java object is created. Th exceptino to this is if thre is an inner class. If there's an inner class then actually, that innner class is created as a separate top-level object- it's its own binary blob.

HTH